# SoundCloud widget custom edit

Tags: mobile, customization, soundcloud, web-widget

I'm using the following code to create a custom SoundCloud player:
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

What I have done is:
http://epopengate.org/wp-content/themes/epopengate/test/examples/sc-player-standard.html

What I would like to do is have the track listing appear when the user clicks on the info button...I would like to save space and I don't really need to display what's being shown in that window anyway. What would I need to change in order to do that? I assume something in the JS file, but I'm not sure what to move around to make it work.

I know there is a widget that works similar here: https://soundcloud.com/pages/widgets - but it's flash based so Apple devices would not be able to use it and by creating a track listing that appears when the Info button is clicked, increases mobile compatibility by allowing the user to click because you can't hover with mobile devices.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 widget, which is the default option for embeds from SoundCloud now – https://blog.soundcloud.com/2011/11/03/html5/

These will work fine on iOS and Android.

Comment: Gryzzly, I have an HTML 5 player that works, I'd just like to tweak it to do what I'd like it to do. I know SoundCloud has an official HTML 5 widget, but it doesn't match the look and feel of the website I am working on - which is why I was trying to create a custom player (which is what I have done for the most part)